# Period at the end of date in AMSart

Tags: amsart, date

How ca I suppress the period at the end auf the date string in amsart? It is formatted as, e.g. 08. August 2016.; but there should be no period after 2016. The example code:

```
%% 
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand{\datename}{}
\title{-- Something --}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redefine the date's definition in the document class (remove the dot at the end - see the comment in the MWE).

```
%% 
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand{\datename}{}% you can remove this line and remove <\datename\ > in the below definition to get the same thing minus the space between the datename and the date itself
\makeatletter
\def\@setdate{\datename\ \@date}% modified from <\def\@setdate{\datename\ \@date\@addpunct.}>
\makeatother
\title{-- Something --}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
%%}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the hin to lock at the cls-file.

Comment: @Ulrich You're welcome but please read [how do we say thank you around here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers),.

Comment: I hope I done it the right way now.